# logback logging with application.yml fails to lookup the properties

Tags: logback, logstash-logback-encoder

logback is unable to evaluate  spring application name

`<property scope="context" name="app_name" value="${spring.application.name}" />  log output:"app_name":"spring.application.name_IS_UNDEFINED"`

if the property is printed out of the application context, it is working fine.

logback-classic 1.11
logback-core 1.11
logstash-logback-encoder 4.11

UPDATE:
changing logback.xml to logback-spring.xml and   adding `<springProperty scope="context" name="app_name" source="spring.application.name" />`

rather than `<property scope="context" name="app_name" value="${spring.application.name}" />` fixed the issue with spring-boot 1.5.4

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: changing logback.xml to logback-spring.xml and adding

rather than  fixed the issue with spring-boot 1.5.4

Comment: In Spring Boot 2.5.5 when I set in logback-spring.xml:
<springProperty scope="context" name="app_name" source="spring.application.name" />

I get "default" String as app_name, not the value of spring.application.name property from application.properties.

Do you know how to resolve it?